# Sling example showing 404

Tags: sling

I have started up the sling launchpad jar and I can access its welcome page at `localhost:8080`. I have created a new sling project in eclipse and started the sling server in eclipse but when I try to access the example at `localhost:8080/content/example.json` it throws a `404` error. Also, there is no content folder in the sling .explorer page that displays the repository in the browser. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: from the info provided its not possible to say what is wrong. can you post a snap of error log  file when you hit that url?

Comment: What version of the sling lanunchpad are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm your issue - I'm having it as well. I'm quite sure this is because you're using the latest sling 8 standalone from http://sling.apache.org/downloads.cgi, as am I, and it doesn't actually come with a content node. The 404 is valid. It's up to you to POST /content into your repo.

The issue is compounded because there's not a trustworthy JCR explorer. I understand you use the .explorer interface, which sometimes bugs out horribly and then you're not sure whether you can ever trust what you're seeing.

Composum provides a *very* trustworth JCR explorer which you should install immediately and use. :) It will be included in the upcoming sling 9 as the standard interface

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.composum.sling.core

You'll want to install these:

- composum-sling-core-commons
- composum-sling-core-console
- composum-sling-core-jslibs
- composum-sling-package-manager
- composum-sling-user-management

You can then access the explorer at /bin/browser.html

Answer (score -1):

You have to login. If you do not have the rights to read a resource, you will get 404.

Comment: One usually gets [403 error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) when (s)he needs to login. [404](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) means _Not found_.

Comment: You are right for the HTTP standard. But this is a special behavior of sling to signal 'nothing to see here'.